# Retrofit Observables and access to Response

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit and RxJava but can't seem to do what I want.

Here's my declaration of my web service:

```
Observable<Response> rawRemoteDownload(@Header("Cookie") String token, @Path("programId") int programId);
```

The problem I have is the webservice is returning a 403 and a json payload with details.

Retrofit calls onError, only passing the Throwable so I can't check the response body.

Here's part of my test code

```
apiManager.rawRemoteDownloadRequest("token", 1).subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // this is called and I've lost the response!
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response response) {

        }
    });
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to Gomino, I went with this as a solution:

```
new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
            if (throwable instanceof RetrofitError) {
                Response response = ((RetrofitError) throwable).getResponse();

                System.out.println(convertToString(response.getBody()));
            }
        }
```

where convertToString looks like:

```
private String convertToString(TypedInput body) {
    byte[] bodyBytes = ((TypedByteArray) body).getBytes();
    return new String(bodyBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the throwable is a RetrofitError:

```
@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
   if (e instanceof RetrofitError) {
      Response response = ((RetrofitError) e).getResponse();
   }
}
```

Comment: just to confirm, Retrofit doesn't give me a POJO of the response once it goes into the error path? I can only see the raw JSon.

Comment: I don't think it is reliable to try to get a POJO if an error is thrown but you can take a look at the getBodyAs method in retrofit error. Take a look at the source code : https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RetrofitError.java